# Automatically prepending '#' to slug in child page permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I'd like to have any child page url like `http://www.foo.com/fooparent/foochild`
automatically turns into `http://www.foo.com/fooparent/#foochild`

Could this be done in the htaccess rewrite rules or can I directly change the way WordPress stores the slug name so I could add # in front of it?

**Use case**

I have the parent pages loading all the child pages content in the template. It's utilizing a onepage layout with anchor links scrolling down the page to each section as you navigate. There are cases where permalinks of the child pages are exposed and that would break the onepage functionality. A child permalink should just load it's parent page and add use its slug as a an #anchor in the URL.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want this, could you edit your question to ellaborate on what your use case is?

Comment: I've added a use case. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: So like a flat website design. #About would scroll down the page until it hits the 'About Page' div, correct?

Comment: @howdy_McGee correct. Whenever a childpage was created, it would prepend '#' to the slug.

Comment: You may be looking for an HTACCESS rule instead of a WordPress work around.